# Como personalizar un spinner en android

Tags: android, spinner

Quiero personalizar un spinner, o crearlo si no hay caso, que tenga un estilo como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que forma se puede hacer?
De momento solo e logrado crear un XML que tenga el fondo del spinner, pero no se como añadirle la flechita.
Para asignarselo lo hice desde la propiedad Background del spinner, y aca el codigo:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#bdfbea"/>

<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#00887b"/>

<padding android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"/>

<corners android:radius="50dp"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**spinner_style.xml**

Agrega otro item y dentro de el un `bitmap` y le pasas tu `ic_arrow.png` en este caso:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#bdfbea" />

                    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#00887b" />

                    <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />

                    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>

                <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow">
                </bitmap>

            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**acitity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_style"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Resultado]

Para jugar con la oritacion de la imagen puede utilizar este

```
   <bitmap android:**gravity="center|right"**
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow">
                </bitmap>


 <bitmap android:**gravity="center|left"**
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow">
                </bitmap>
```

Comment: Si supiera donde vivis ,iria a abrazarte! Gracias!!! es lo que buscaba, simple, consiso, y respondiste rapidisimo, una lastima que mi reputacion no me deje ademas votar tu respuesta :/